# php imagejpeg mime type

Tags: php, image, gd

I am using php's imagejpeg to save a GD image resource to a file, doing this:

```
imagejpeg($im, '../images/' . $image_id . '.jpg');
```

It works fine, but according to my browser, it tries to read the file as text/plain:

> Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/plain.

Is there a step before saving the file that I am supposed to do to make sure it's using the right mine-type?

I am using windows (XAMPP), could it be a Windows issue?
EDIT: nope. I just tested in a linux server.

As far as the actual displaying, it's just plain html .
My upload code is supposed to saves= the file as a plain jpeg in the server. It's just not saving it with the right mime type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Apache server - in standard out of the box configuration - should sent content-type headers purely based upon file extension. Apache shouldn't even even be looking at the contents or how it was originally generated/stored.

On my out-of-the-box Apache2, the file conf/mime.types contains the line:

`image/jpeg jpeg jpg jpe`

which ought to do it, right?

Can you post a test-case, say, a simple html page with two img tags: one for your generated image, and one for a standard image that seems to work fine?

One last thought: Does it occur in all browsers? Maybe it's a browser issue, not a server one?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're dumping the contents of the file to the browser and not actually telling the browser what type of file it is.  Try adding a Content-type header before you output your image to the browser:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: no no, I actually display my images the old fashion way: <img src="../images/2.jpg" />. My upload script saves a static jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't using the wrong file-extension name?
Otherwise, just put an normal image in the server and make sure the mime-types are properly configured.
It could also be that your image data from the manipulation is corrupted.

Comment: My file extensions are .jpg.
I just tested by manually upload an image, and the mime type is correct there. So it's really about the way the php SAVES the image on the server.